# YiiBooster how to make a button add a row on the next line

Tags: php, javascript, yii, yii-booster

**Hello everyone.**

I have a view file, in which there is an inline form with three text inputs and one button. I need to generate three same inputs and a button on the next line when clicking on this button.

Please help.

Here's the code:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'warehouse-form',
    'type' => 'inline',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'productName',array('class'=>'span3','maxlength'=>255)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'cost',array('class'=>'span3')); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($model,'imported_at',array('class'=>'span3')); ?>

    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
        'label' => 'One more',
        'size' => 'mini'
    )); ?>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit',
            'type'=>'primary',
            'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
        )); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

P.S. Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code that you have?

Comment: Check this want something like this ?? http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/extension?view=dynamicrows

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!